# Failed NVMe M.2 SSD, broken filesystem, unwriteable; can I wipe it anyway?

Tags: filesystems, security, data-recovery, hardware, ssd

My Samsung 970 EVO M.2 500GB SSD (MZ-V7E500BW) suddenly failed yesterday during a power outage.

I now have a warning during POST ("WARNING! Please back up your data and replace your hard disk drive.
WARNING! Your HDD/SSD might crash at any moment."). The last time I rebooted before this was about 5 days earlier, and the warning was not present then.

By booting a live USB stick I managed to check the SMART log:

```
Smart Log for NVME device:nvme0 namespace-id:ffffffff
critical_warning                        : 0x8
temperature                             : 49 C
available_spare                         : 29%
available_spare_threshold               : 10%
percentage_used                         : 0%
endurance group critical warning summary: 0
data_units_read                         : 4,948,748
data_units_written                      : 20,573,476
host_read_commands                      : 100,316,217
host_write_commands                     : 357,643,056
controller_busy_time                    : 1,790
power_cycles                            : 24
power_on_hours                          : 4,570
unsafe_shutdowns                        : 11
media_errors                            : 41
num_err_log_entries                     : 70
Warning Temperature Time                : 0
Critical Composite Temperature Time     : 0
Temperature Sensor 1           : 49 C
Temperature Sensor 2           : 74 C
Thermal Management T1 Trans Count       : 0
Thermal Management T2 Trans Count       : 0
Thermal Management T1 Total Time        : 0
Thermal Management T2 Total Time        : 0
```

Messages from the kernel mentioning `nvme` during startup of the live USB OS:

```
Oct 26 19:18:58 ubuntu kernel: [    1.233479] nvme nvme0: pci function 0000:06:00.0
Oct 26 19:18:58 ubuntu kernel: [    1.243303] nvme nvme0: missing or invalid SUBNQN field.
Oct 26 19:18:58 ubuntu kernel: [    1.243323] nvme nvme0: Shutdown timeout set to 8 seconds
Oct 26 19:18:58 ubuntu kernel: [    1.252449] nvme nvme0: 4/0/0 default/read/poll queues
Oct 26 19:18:58 ubuntu kernel: [    1.254855]  nvme0n1: p1 p2 p3
Oct 26 19:18:58 ubuntu kernel: [    3.629244] EXT4-fs (nvme0n1p2): INFO: recovery required on readonly filesystem
Oct 26 19:18:58 ubuntu kernel: [    3.629246] EXT4-fs (nvme0n1p2): write access will be enabled during recovery
Oct 26 19:18:58 ubuntu kernel: [    3.674861] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev nvme0n1, sector 124928 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 4 prio class 0
Oct 26 19:18:58 ubuntu kernel: [    3.674893] Buffer I/O error on dev nvme0n1p2, logical block 0, lost async page write
Oct 26 19:18:58 ubuntu kernel: [    3.674913] Buffer I/O error on dev nvme0n1p2, logical block 1, lost async page write
Oct 26 19:18:58 ubuntu kernel: [    3.674931] Buffer I/O error on dev nvme0n1p2, logical block 2, lost async page write
Oct 26 19:18:58 ubuntu kernel: [    3.674949] Buffer I/O error on dev nvme0n1p2, logical block 3, lost async page write
Oct 26 19:18:58 ubuntu kernel: [    3.674967] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev nvme0n1, sector 133200 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Oct 26 19:18:58 ubuntu kernel: [    3.674995] Buffer I/O error on dev nvme0n1p2, logical block 1034, lost async page write
Oct 26 19:18:58 ubuntu kernel: [    3.675013] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev nvme0n1, sector 133384 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Oct 26 19:18:58 ubuntu kernel: [    3.675040] Buffer I/O error on dev nvme0n1p2, logical block 1057, lost async page write
Oct 26 19:18:58 ubuntu kernel: [    3.675059] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev nvme0n1, sector 147176 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Oct 26 19:18:58 ubuntu kernel: [    3.675086] Buffer I/O error on dev nvme0n1p2, logical block 2781, lost async page write
Oct 26 19:18:58 ubuntu kernel: [    3.675105] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev nvme0n1, sector 4319360 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Oct 26 19:18:58 ubuntu kernel: [    3.675132] Buffer I/O error on dev nvme0n1p2, logical block 524304, lost async page write
Oct 26 19:18:58 ubuntu kernel: [    3.675151] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev nvme0n1, sector 4319488 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Oct 26 19:18:58 ubuntu kernel: [    3.675178] Buffer I/O error on dev nvme0n1p2, logical block 524320, lost async page write
Oct 26 19:18:58 ubuntu kernel: [    3.675197] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev nvme0n1, sector 4319544 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 2 prio class 0
Oct 26 19:18:58 ubuntu kernel: [    3.675224] Buffer I/O error on dev nvme0n1p2, logical block 524327, lost async page write
Oct 26 19:18:58 ubuntu kernel: [    3.675243] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev nvme0n1, sector 4319816 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Oct 26 19:18:58 ubuntu kernel: [    3.675270] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev nvme0n1, sector 4320256 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Oct 26 19:18:58 ubuntu kernel: [    3.675297] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev nvme0n1, sector 4320936 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Oct 26 19:18:58 ubuntu kernel: [    3.729319] EXT4-fs (nvme0n1p2): error loading journal
Oct 26 19:18:58 ubuntu kernel: [    3.743157] EXT4-fs (nvme0n1p3): INFO: recovery required on readonly filesystem
Oct 26 19:18:58 ubuntu kernel: [    3.743158] EXT4-fs (nvme0n1p3): write access will be enabled during recovery
Oct 26 19:18:58 ubuntu kernel: [    3.806113] EXT4-fs (nvme0n1p3): error loading journal
Oct 26 19:19:04 ubuntu kernel: [   30.724414] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev nvme0n1, sector 0 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 0 prio class 0
Oct 26 19:19:04 ubuntu kernel: [   30.752254] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev nvme0n1, sector 0 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 0 prio class 0
Oct 26 19:19:05 ubuntu kernel: [   31.346630] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev nvme0n1, sector 0 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 0 prio class 0
Oct 26 19:19:05 ubuntu kernel: [   31.365831] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev nvme0n1, sector 0 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 0 prio class 0
Oct 26 19:19:29 ubuntu kernel: [   55.502099] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev nvme0n1, sector 0 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 0 prio class 0
Oct 26 19:19:29 ubuntu kernel: [   55.516704] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev nvme0n1, sector 0 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 0 prio class 0
Oct 26 19:24:44 ubuntu kernel: [  370.116101] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev nvme0n1, sector 0 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 0 prio class 0
Oct 26 19:24:44 ubuntu kernel: [  370.130330] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev nvme0n1, sector 0 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 0 prio class 0
```

Thanks to `ddrescue` I managed to clone all of its partitions to a different machine over the network. There were IO errors while extracting both ext4 partitions but with enough retries it eventually got everything.

After that I was able to run `e2fsck` on the images, which appeared to succeed, and now I can mount them as read-only loop devices. Data appears to be intact.

I suppose the first question is **is there anything I can do to fix whatever the problem is, and keep using this drive?** I'm assuming not, but I'm definitely open to suggestions.

If I try to run `fsck` on one of the partitions from the live USB, this is what happens. I tried all combinations of answers to the questions as you'll see below. I can't understand enough of the manual pages and don't know enough about filesystems or drives to know what options, if any, might help me.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fsck /dev/nvme0n1p3
fsck from util-linux 2.36.1
e2fsck 1.46.3 (27-Jul-2021)
/dev/nvme0n1p3: recovering journal
Superblock needs_recovery flag is clear, but journal has data.
Run journal anyway<y>? yes
fsck.ext4: Input/output error while recovering journal of /dev/nvme0n1p3
fsck.ext4: unable to set superblock flags on /dev/nvme0n1p3


/dev/nvme0n1p3: ********** WARNING: Filesystem still has errors **********

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fsck /dev/nvme0n1p3
fsck from util-linux 2.36.1
e2fsck 1.46.3 (27-Jul-2021)
/dev/nvme0n1p3: recovering journal
Superblock needs_recovery flag is clear, but journal has data.
Run journal anyway<y>? no
Clear journal<y>? no
fsck.ext4: Input/output error while recovering journal of /dev/nvme0n1p3
fsck.ext4: unable to set superblock flags on /dev/nvme0n1p3


/dev/nvme0n1p3: ********** WARNING: Filesystem still has errors **********

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fsck /dev/nvme0n1p3
fsck from util-linux 2.36.1
e2fsck 1.46.3 (27-Jul-2021)
/dev/nvme0n1p3: recovering journal
Superblock needs_recovery flag is clear, but journal has data.
Run journal anyway<y>? no
Clear journal<y>? yes
fsck.ext4: Input/output error while recovering journal of /dev/nvme0n1p3
fsck.ext4: unable to set superblock flags on /dev/nvme0n1p3


/dev/nvme0n1p3: ********** WARNING: Filesystem still has errors **********

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

I believe the drive is still under warranty, and I'm trying to get in contact with Samsung support to try to get a replacement or refund.

If they ask me to send it back, that's going to pose a problem since there's sensitive data on this drive.

The drive resists all attempts to write to it. I can't mount it and write to it normally. The kernel emits IO errors if I try to write to it at the block level. Even Samsung's secure erase tool (their Windows-only software offers to produce a bootable USB drive with such a tool) fails.

**Is there some way to force secure erasure of this device?**

Comment: Does your computers bios have an option to secure erase the drive? Failing that, `hdparm` does have some *security erase* options

Comment: I found a secure erase tool in there but it doesn't do NVMe. I also found an old Windows hard drive, put that in, installed Samsung's software, and hoped that would let me clear the "read only" flag but nope. It also has a firmware update option, which fails (possibly because the drive is read-only?), and it also offers to make a bootable USB stick with an NVMe secure eraser tool. I did this, and that too fails, presumably also because the drive is read-only. So I have to ask now... what's the best way to destroy the NVMe without signs of physical damage...?

Comment: I can look into `hdparm` but in all the hoops I've jumped through today I've overwritten my Linux live USB. Writing it again now...

Comment: I'm still waiting for a response from Samsung about whether there's some way I can reset the flag, but in the mean time I got permission from Amazon, to whom I'm returning the item, to physically damage it, and they say they'll still refund me. I'll give Samsung one more day, then I guess I'll pull some chips off the thing.

Comment: guess that's easier than bombarding it with cosmic radiation :D

Answer (score 0):

Your are never too carefully : I have managed to get many files from a file system attacked by the Chernobyl virus !

To erase data, you can do a `dd bs=1M if=/dev/zero of=/dev/…` but if it stops somewhere, you may have to restart it with the `skip` option and skip some blocks.

With NVRAM, this could not erase some block but reallocates some… but we would need a really low level access to get the unerased blocks. Ok for personal sensitive data, not for military secret data !

Comment: Trying to write to it with `dd` exits with a success code, but the kernel emits errors like `blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev nvme0n1, sector 0 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 0 prio class 0`. If I run `sync` and then read off the first bytes, I can see that they were not changed.

Comment: How does this answer the OP's question(?)

Comment: You can try `dd` with the `seek=…` option in case only the first sectors can’t be written. @LinuxSecurityFreak : the OP asked for a way to erase a file system which can’t be mounted. I answer with `dd` which is typically a program designed to do this kind of job.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think it was necessarily a bad answer. It didn't help in my case (doesn't help with `seek` either), and my clarification in my question about the drive resisting all attempts to write to it was added after the answer was given. I don't think it deserves downvotes!

Comment: Did you install nvme-cli? If you can do the sanitize command which totally & quickly erases the entire drive. https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Solid_state_drive/Memory_cell_clearing